# How to change Object repository if the title of window changes which i had recorded

Tags: automation, qtp

I have an QTP automation scripts to install a software.
The window that I recorded has got it's tiltle changed.
Now the QTP is not able to recognize the window.

So should i re-record the full installation or is there a way through which i could run QTP automation by changing values in object repository?

I tried to change the name of title in Object repository but it was of no help.

Please reply soon.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `title` property of the window in the object repository, there you can either give a different value or use a regular expression. Is this what you tried?

Another option is to use a **Maintenance Mode Run** which will give you the option to point at your window and help you decide how to fix the test.

Comment: Thanks A lot.The regular expression worked for me and Maintenance mode is also quite helpful.